# Pycharm Can not find the reference to external javascript and css files

Tags: django, pycharm

I am not able to locate my external javascript and css files when I ctrl click their path string. [image: screentshot]

My html template path is `'bodhitree-flipped/concept/templates/concept/content_developer.html`'. And my external video.js file path is '`bodhitree-flipped/video/static/video-js/video.js`'.

Any Idea how I make pycharm to locate my js files?  <s>I know the solution for this is to run `python manage.py collectstatic` command which will copy all my asset files to `/staticfiles` folder but I don't want to do it as it will increase the size of my project by duplicating all the static files.</s>

I tried rebuiding the file index with option under File->invalidate caches/Restart... but unfortunately this also doesn't work.

This is how my project structure look like.

[image: project structure]

click on the file to see code in [settings.py](http://pastebin.com/ZJb4RNEV)

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I'm not at my computer atm so can't remember exactly but if you right click the static directory in the file structure there is an option to set the directory as a content root or something like that..

Comment: I have access to my computer, so you can try: `Right click` -> `Mark directory as`: -> `Resource Root`

Comment: no, it is not working.

Comment: you have your static root file, etc setup in settings correctly?

Comment: I don't think we need to change any default settings to enable this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just changed the python template language from jinja to Django (settings->languages and framework->python template languages)and then invalidated the file cache. It worked.